# Cannot seem to get my rails server to run from cloud c9.io service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I cannot seem to get my server to run on c9.io after trying many attempts to update the Gemfile and do bundle update and bundle install commands it still seems to get caught up on the sass rails gem.

```
`master) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/toy_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

With my current gems being the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
# See  for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: 
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
gem 'jbuilder'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: 
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gemfile to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

run:

```
$ bundle install --without production
```

Then making sure you're in your toy_app directory, run:

```
$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```